# Validate an email and display message inside a span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, email

I have this simple code here about the input type email. I have some reference about validating an email when user clicks the button. Here's the reference [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript](http://Validate%20email%20address%20in%20JavaScript?)

**HTML code**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" type="email" required>
        <span id="checkEmail"></span>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<html>
```

I tried the script to validate and display a message in the span tag id="checkEmail" using keyup event function but it doesn't seem to work. Does my syntax is incorrect? Please help.

Its **Script**

```
<script>
//Email Regular Expression function
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

//Email Validate function
function validate() {
    $("#email").keyup(function() {

        var email = $("#email").val();
        if (validateEmail(email)) {
            $("#checkEmail").text(email + " is valid :)");
            $("#checkEmail").css("color", "green");
        } else {
            $("#checkEmail").text(email + " is not valid :(");
            $("#checkEmail").css("color", "red");
        }
    });

   //UPDATE
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkEmail").keyup(validate);
   });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Check the link mate.

Comment: you have 2 different jquery libraries linked. Keep one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me, all I needed to do is to call

```
validate();
```

anywhere on document load to actually bind the events.

(which means you might want to move the binding outside the validate function, to not re-bind it anytime you click/use the function)

edit:
I have prepared a fiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/caz9o53e/

Comment: Could you provide a JSFIDDLE on this sir?

Comment: in the JSFIDDLE sir, it actually works. But in testing it to my file. It will not work. How come? It does not work on javascript 1.7

Comment: There must be a difference, either in your library set or in your code. Can you post / fiddle your version, which is not working?

Comment: That's why it won't work sir, cause I post the code without the script tag

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this fiddle link, does the work.

http://jsfiddle.net/o6d86xtw/1/

HTML

```
<label for="email" id="email">Hey!</label>
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="required" /> 
<span class="msg error">You shall not pass!</span>
<span class="msg success">You can pass!</span>
```

JQuery

```
var component = {
    input   : $('input[name="email"]'),
    mensage : {
        fields  : $('.msg'),
        success : $('.success'),
        error   : $('.error')
    }
},
   regex  = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/;

component.input.blur(function () {
    component.mensage.fields.hide();
    regex.test(component.input.val()) ? component.mensage.success.show() : component.mensage.error.show();
});
```

Note : I forked someone else's fiddle.

Comment: But e.g `java.the.hutt@gmail.com` is valid email

Comment: @A.Wolff Regex is not his problem I guess. He can use whichever regex he wants. I am deleting this anyway, makes no sense.

Comment: You are correct, no really way to validate email from regex

Comment: I meant that the answer makes no sense.

Comment: Well this could answer it but it isn't, imho

Comment: Okay let me make amends then.